# How do repeated roots of the discriminant correspond to the order of repeated roots in the original polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, algebraic-curves, covering-spaces, discriminant

**Background/context:**

If $S \subset \mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$ is a smooth curve with bidegree $(d_1, d_2)$, we know that its genus is $(d_1 - 1)(d_2 - 1)$ for example by the adjunction formula.

Alternatively, we can attempt to compute the genus via the Riemann-Hurwitz formula as follows:

1. Write $S = \{P(z,w) = 0\}$ where $z, w$ are in $\mathbb{CP}^1$.
2. The projection map $p$ onto the first factor is a $d_2$-sheeted branched cover. The branch points $z_i$ occur exactly when the polynomial $P(z_i, w)$ has repeated roots (when considered as a polynomial in $w$, treating $z_i$ as coefficients).
3. These repeated roots are detected by the discriminant of $P(z_i, w)$, which has degree $2d_2 - 2$ in the "coefficients". But the coefficients are homogeneous of degree $d_1$ in $z$, so the discriminant is a degree $d_1(2d_2-2)$ polynomial in $z$.
4. Computing $\chi(S) = 2d_2 - d_1(2d_2 - 2)$, we actually get exactly the correct genus for $S$! This means $d_1(2d_2 - 2)$ precisely counts the ramification $\sum (e_p - 1)$ of the branched cover.

**Question:**

Given the above context, it must be the case that the degree of the discriminant counts *exactly* the number of roots of $P(z,w)$ which are lost due to branching of $(z,w) \mapsto z$. Why is this the case? There are basically two opposing forces which must somehow cancel out:

- If the *discriminant* has a repeated root, then downstairs it corresponds to losing a branch point.
- If a branch point has ramification index greater than two, then upstairs it corresponds to "the vanishing of the discriminant" not accounting for *all* of the repeated roots which are lost at this branch point.

I have no idea why these two phenomena should cancel out, and would love some insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting no engagement here, I cross-posted the question to Math Overflow. I received some answers there, and will accordingly close this post.

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466758/what-relationship-is-there-between-repeated-roots-of-discriminants-and-orders-of